# TSQL Merge Performance

Tags: performance, t-sql, merge

*Scenario*:

I have a table with roughly 24 million records.  The table has pricing history related to individual customers and is computed daily.  There are on average 6 million records for each day. Every morning a the price list is generated and a merge statement is ran to reflect the changes in their pricing.

The merge statement begins with the previous day's previous data being inserted into a variable table, that table is then merged into the actual table.  The main problem is that the merge statement takes pretty long.

**My real question centers around the performance of using a variable table vs physical table vs temp table. What is the best practice for large merges like this?**

Comment: Depending on how much RAM you have, with 6M rows, there's a good chance SQL Server is already converting your table variable into a temp. table behind the scenes.

Comment: Turns out the TLOG built up at a very quick rate.  Handled this by some batch deletes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thoughts

I'd consider a temp table: these have statistics which will help. A table variable is always assumed to have one row. Also, the IO can be shunted onto separate drives (assuming you have tempdb separately)

If a single transaction is not required, I'd split the MERGE too into a DELETE, UPDATE, INSERT sequence to reduce the amount of work needed in each action (which reduces the amount of rollback info needed and the amount of locking etc

Comment: Hi gbn, can you clarify this a little please sir. Are you saying that a T-SQL MERGE operation is more expensive than the equivalent three individual operations?

Comment: @JohnSansom: not sure really. However, I have read some stuff (@AaronBertrand ?) that suggests a MERGE may be expensive, perhaps if you're doing jhe JFDI pattern http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A27535+JFDI. Saying that, I use MERGE a lot now in SQL Server 2012 and I haven't seen any issues

Answer (score 0):

Check if you indexes on the tables.  Indexes would be updated every time you add/delete records on that table.

Try removing the indexes before merging the records and then re-create it again after the merge.

Comment: Index's really aren't the issue as the table is very heavily indexed.  The merge statement does not insert the records anywhere, it is used primarily for the output which is written to a csv file for export.

Comment: @kaiopur: your statement "the merge statement does not insert the records anywhere" sounds radically different than your question.  You need to post some code.

Comment: 433s: I'll give it a shot and get back to you.

Answer (score 0):

Temp tables often perform better than table variables for large data sets. Additionally you can put the data into the temp table and then index it.